# Add buttons to UIPickerView - Swift 1.2

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uipickerview

I would like to add two `UIButtons` in the `UIPickerView` (on top of it). Please take a look at the `Cancel` and `Done` buttons in this image:

[image]

How can I do it?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I have solved this, answer in Swift:

```
var pickerView = UIPickerView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 200, view.frame.width, 300))
pickerView.backgroundColor = .whiteColor()
pickerView.showsSelectionIndicator = true

var toolBar = UIToolbar()
toolBar.barStyle = UIBarStyle.Default
toolBar.translucent = true
toolBar.tintColor = UIColor(red: 76/255, green: 217/255, blue: 100/255, alpha: 1)
toolBar.sizeToFit()


let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Bordered, target: self, action: "donePicker")
let spaceButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.FlexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
let cancelButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Cancel", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Bordered, target: self, action: "canclePicker")

toolBar.setItems([cancelButton, spaceButton, doneButton], animated: false)
toolBar.userInteractionEnabled = true

textField.inputView = pickerView
textField.inputAccessoryView = toolBar
```

Comment: Where have you declared "textLabel"? Is this a label populated by your UIPickerViews selection?

Comment: TextLabel is an UILabel outlet, so when you try to "edit" the label, the pickerView will appear.

Comment: I mean UITextField, sorry

Comment: Please could you tell me how did you write the selected name into the textFiled? @DejanSkledar

Comment: pickerView has a method selectedRowInComponent, so you get the index of the selected row, and then you just do: textField.text = yourData[indexOrSelectedRow]

Comment: @DejanSkledar how do you implement those custom actions that you defined for the UIBarButtonItems (donePicker and cancelPicker) - what does the syntax for that look like?

Comment: In Swift 2.2 you just create a function, like: `func donePicker() { ... }`, and in UIBarButtonItem action you set: `#selector(donePicker)`

Comment: What if i am not using textfield. i want show picker on button click. Then i am not able to do like pickerFilter?.inputAccessoryView = barAccessory........Eror is this inputAccessoryView is get-only property.  any solution pls.

Answer (score 2):

See Mine. I have Collection View and UIPicker to select photo Folders.

[image]

```
//MARK:- SHOW PHOTO FOLDER BUTTON METHOD
@IBAction func photoFolderListButtonClicked(sender: UIButton) {
    self.navigationItem.setHidesBackButton(true, animated: true)

    //Making PickerView of Competitors
    let DEVICE_SCREEN_WIDTH =    UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width
    photoFolderListPicker.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 44.0, DEVICE_SCREEN_WIDTH, 260)
    photoFolderListPicker.dataSource = self
    photoFolderListPicker.delegate = self
    photoFolderListPicker.showsSelectionIndicator = true;
    photoFolderListPicker.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

    let pickerDateToolbar = UIToolbar(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, DEVICE_SCREEN_WIDTH, 44))
    pickerDateToolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyle.Black
    pickerDateToolbar.barTintColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    pickerDateToolbar.translucent = true

    //Cancel button on photoFolderListPicker
    let barItems = NSMutableArray()
    let labelCancel = UILabel()
    labelCancel.text = " Cancel"

    let titleCancel = UIBarButtonItem(title: labelCancel.text, style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: Selector("cancelPickerSelectionButtonClicked:"))
    titleCancel.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    barItems.addObject(titleCancel)

    var flexSpace: UIBarButtonItem
    flexSpace = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.FlexibleSpace, target: self, action: nil)
    barItems.addObject(flexSpace)

    //Done Button on photoFolderListPicker
    let doneBtn = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.Done, target: self, action: Selector("photoFolderSelectionDone:"))
    barItems.addObject(doneBtn)
    doneBtn.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

    pickerDateToolbar.setItems(barItems as [AnyObject] as? [UIBarButtonItem], animated: true)
    actionView.addSubview(pickerDateToolbar)
    actionView.addSubview(photoFolderListPicker)

    if (window != nil) {
        window!.addSubview(actionView)
    }
    else {
        self.view.addSubview(actionView)
    }
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.2, animations: {
        self.actionView.frame = CGRectMake(0, UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.height - 250.0, UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width, 250)
    })
}
//MARK:- PICKERVIEW DELEGATE METHODS
func pickerView(_pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    return model.documentFolders.count
}
func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(_pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 1
}
func pickerView(_pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String! {
    return model.documentFolders[row].value
}
//MARK:- PICKERVIEW BUTTON METHODS
func cancelPickerSelectionButtonClicked(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    self.navigationItem.setHidesBackButton(false, animated: true)

    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.2, animations: {
        self.actionView.frame = CGRectMake(0, UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.height, UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width, 210.0)
        }, completion: { _ in
            for obj: AnyObject in self.actionView.subviews {
                if let view = obj as? UIView
                {
                    view.removeFromSuperview()
                }
            }
    })
    photoFolderListButton.setTitle(" "+"Select Folder", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
}
func photoFolderSelectionDone(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    uploadedPhotoFolderName?.isEmpty
    loadedFromPageSection = "fromPhotoFolderSelectionDone"
    self.disableScoutDetailUserInterfaceElementsDutingApiCall()

    //setting selectedPhotoFolderItem and selectedPhotoFolderItemId
    let myRow = photoFolderListPicker.selectedRowInComponent(0)
    selectedPhotoFolderItem =  model.documentFolders[myRow].value!
    selectedPhotoFolderItemId = Int(model.documentFolders[myRow].key!)

    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.2, animations: {
        self.actionView.frame = CGRectMake(0, UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.height, UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width, 260.0)
        }, completion: { _ in
            for obj: AnyObject in self.actionView.subviews {
                if let view = obj as? UIView
                {
                    view.removeFromSuperview()
                }
            }
    })
    photoFolderListButton.setTitle(" "+(selectedPhotoFolderItem as? String)!, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    self.view.makeToastActivityWithMessage(message: "Fetching")

    //Delegate is added to class after popViewControllerAnimated(true) called
    model.delegate = self

    //API CALL - Fetching Photos
    AppController().fetchPropertyPhotosGallery(hbId, propertyId: scoutPropertyId, fileTypeId: selectedPhotoFolderItemId)

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I do it in ObjC to add a picker popup with buttons to a text field. Should be simple enough to translate into swift. Basically you create the picker and assign it to the text `inputView`. Then you create a toolbar which you assign to the text `inputAccessoryView` which sits on top of the `inputView` when it pops up.

```
self.manufacturerPicker = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
self.manufacturerPicker.delegate = self;
self.manufacturerPicker.dataSource = self;
[self.manufacturerPicker setShowsSelectionIndicator:YES];
self.filterByManufacturerTextField.inputView = self.manufacturerPicker;

UIToolbar *manufacturerPickerToolbar=[[UIToolbar alloc] init];
manufacturerPickerToolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlack;
manufacturerPickerToolbar.translucent = YES;
manufacturerPickerToolbar.tintColor = nil;
[manufacturerPickerToolbar sizeToFit];

UIBarButtonItem *doneButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Done"
                                                                style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self
                                                              action:@selector(manufacturerPickerDoneClicked:)];
UIBarButtonItem *spacerButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil];
UIBarButtonItem *cancelButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Cancel"
                                                                style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self
                                                               action:@selector(manufacturerPickerCancelClicked:)];

[manufacturerPickerToolbar setItems:@[cancelButton,spacerButton,doneButton]];
self.filterByManufacturerTextField.inputAccessoryView = manufacturerPickerToolbar;
```

**Updated for when you have no UITextField as the start point:**

If you want to launch a picker from a cell as if it was a text field picker, I believe you have to make your UITableViewCell implement the process of becoming the first responder.

To do this I think the process is to implement the `UIResponder` protocol in your cell.

1) override `canBecomeFirstResponder` and return YES.

2) override `inputView` property getter. In this code return your UIPickerView.

§3) override `inputAccessoryView` property getter. In this code return your UIToolbar.

Now in your cell when you select the cell, make the cell become the first responder by calling `[self becomeFirstResponder];`.

This should then bring the picker and toolbar up properly I think. There may be more to this.

When cancel or done, drop it using `[self resignFirstResponder];`

Not done this before, but I think this is the general process.

**Option 2 (Cheat):**

Sometimes cheating is easier. Add a hidden UITextField at the back of your cell or add one which is 0 width. Set its inputView and inputAccessoryView as per the original suggestion.

Then when you select the cell simply make the UITextField the first responder using `[self.<your text field property> becomeFirstResponder];`

This should give you the same result via the back door.

Comment: I tried this, but It doesn't seems to work on Swift 1.2 :/ It just doesnt show anything.

Comment: What are you launching the picker from? A UITextView or something else? Also there was a bug in the simulator (if you are only using that) which did not show popup pickers properly if you had hardware keyboard set to on in the simulator. On the simulator menu  uncheck Hardware -> Keyboard -> Connect Hardware Keyboard and try your code again. Otherwise can you post your setup code?

Comment: New problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28760292/uibarbuttonitem-not-clickable-in-uitoolbar

Comment: Does this mean this answer solved your initial problem of adding buttons? If so please accept this one and I will move to the new problem otherwise you have the same issue in two questions running.

Comment: Unfortionatlly I still cannot present the UIPickerView with the UIToolBar, in the other question, I tried it with addSubView, in this question, I'm trying it with inputAccessoryView...

Comment: Updated answer with suggestions dealing with non UITextField as picker launch. Two methods: proper mechanism and a cheat mechanism which I think might get you running quickly.