# Shrink UITableView -> Black Background

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, uiviewanimation

I create a UIDatePicker outside of the screen and when a button is pressed, I want it to slide into the screen (from below).
To give it enough place, I want the UITableView (inside UITableViewController) to shrink over the y-axis.

It kind of works, but the shrinking of the UITableView reveals a black background, so that the UIDatePicker is not shown. How can I fix that?

It looks like this:

[image]

```
import UIKit

class jSONTableViewController: UITableViewController {



    @IBAction func viewDatePicker(sender: UIButton) {
        // Create DatePicker
        let datePicker = UIDatePicker()
        datePicker.center.y = self.view.bounds.height+100
        datePicker.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerMode.Date
        self.view.insertSubview(datePicker, aboveSubview: self.view)



        // Animate View
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, delay: 0, options: .CurveEaseInOut, animations: { () -> Void in
            let heightOfDatepicker = datePicker.frame.height
            datePicker.center.y = self.view.frame.height-(heightOfDatepicker)
            self.tableView.frame = CGRectMake( self.tableView.frame.origin.x,  self.tableView.frame.origin.x,  self.tableView.frame.size.width, self.tableView.frame.height-heightOfDatepicker)

        }, completion: nil)


    }






    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
        // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false

        // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
        // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

Comment: You should use a UIViewController for this so that the table view and the date picker are both subviews of the controller's self.view. In a UITableViewController, the table view is the controller's self.view.

Comment: You should be changing the `contentInsets` of your table view instead of resizing it.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a UITableViewController where the super view is the table view. So when you resize the table view you also rezise the super view which shows the window's background.

You can create a UIViewController and add a table view as a subview, you'll need conform to UITableViewDelegate and UITableViewDataSource too.

Answer (score 0):

I think your best bet would be to use the first responder to bring up a picker from the bottom. Most of this is all done for you, you just need to do some wiring. This gives you the equivalent of how the keyboard works but with your picker instead and optional buttons.

Discussion here today on how best to do this: [Add buttons to UIPickerView - Swift 1.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28720606/add-buttons-to-uipickerview-swift-1-2/28721459#28721459)

This has some swift code you can perhaps just lift and use.