# how can I make a particular textfield uneditable when using shouldChangeCharactersInRange function

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfielddelegate

I am working on my sign up page that has 4 text fields. One of the `text fields` works as Picker-view, when users `tap` on it a `picker-view` will pop up with options to choose from.

The question is how can I make that particular `textfield` `uneditable`? (not all of the the text fields).

I tried using

```
func textField(textField: UITextField!, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String!) -> Bool {

return false
}
```

but the problem is that it made all my text fields uneditable.

I also can't use `textField.userInteractionEnabled = false`, because then I wont be able to tap on the textfield to show the `picker-view`.

thank you.

Comment: would you share how you added uitextfields? did you set inputview as picker view for one of the text field that works as Picker-view?

Comment: dragged the UItextfields to the UIviewcontroller, created outlet and added UItextfeilds delegate, then I used this link to help me create the pickerview. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28720606/add-buttons-to-uipickerview-swift-1-2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can keep a reference to the text field and compare against it in your delegate method:

```
func textField(textField: UITextField!, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String!) -> Bool {
    if textField == self.myTextField {
         return false 
    }
    return true
}
```

Another option that I've employed is to place a UIView over top of the text field with a gesture recognizer to intercept the the touch and call the picker or perform whatever code you want performed on touching the field.

Answer (score 1):

Compare the reference to the textfield you do not want to edit with the one you get in the argument to the method.

```
if self.uneditableTextField == textField {
     //do not edit
}
```

you can also use `guard` for this kind of purpose

Comment: @user3700449 you can consider upvoting :)